# Aggregating results of downstream parameterised jobs in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins Build job which triggers multiple Test jobs with the test name as a parameter using the Jenkins Parameterized Trigger Plugin. This kicks off a number of test builds on multiple executors which all run correctly.

I now want to aggregate the results using 'Aggregate downstream test results->Automatically aggregate all downstream tests'. I have enabled this in the Build job and have set up fingerprinting so that these are recognised as downstream jobs. In the Build jobs lastBuild page I can see that they are recognised as downstream builds:

> Downstream Builds
>
> Test #1-#3

When I click on "Aggregated Test Results" however it only shows the latest of these (Test #3). This may be good behaviour if the job always runs the same tests but mine all run different parts of my test suite.

Is there some way I can get this to aggregate all of the relevant downstream Test builds?

Additional:
Aggregated Test Results does work if you replicate the Test job. This is not ideal as I have a large number of test suites.

Comment: I've had so much trouble with aggregating downstream test results that I ended up aggregating them 'manually' myself: waiting until the downstream jobs finish and copying the test reports over to the parent.

Comment: Having got the automatic aggregation working (by replicating a job) I can see it's not really what I hoped (it doesn't merge the test hierarchies, or do aggregate graphs). I would accept a solution that did it manually, for parameterised jobs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll outline the manual solution (as mentioned in the comments), and provide more details if you need them later:

Let *P* be the parent job and *D* be a downstream job (you can easily extend the approach to multiple downstream jobs).

1. An instance (build) of *P* invokes *D* via [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) via a build step (**not** as a post-build step) and waits for *D*'s to finish. Along with other parameters, *P* passes to *D* a parameter - let's call it *PARENT_ID* - based on *P*'s build's *BUILD_ID*.
2. *D* executes the tests and archives them as artifacts (along with jUnit reports - if applicable).
3. *P* then executes an external Python (or internal Groovy) script that finds the appropriate build of *D* via *PARENT_ID* (you iterate over builds of *D* and examine the value of *PARENT_ID* parameter). The script then copies the artifacts from *D* to *P* and *P* publishes them.

If using Python (that's what I do) - utilize [Python JenkinsAPI wrapper](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/jenkinsapi). If using Groovy - utilize [Groovy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin) and run your script as system script. You then can access Jenkins via its [Java API](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/).

Comment: The issue with that flow is that P will not yet have archived its artifacts. Normally you'd tests the artifacts, so you'd have to split it down even further.

Comment: @malenkiy_scot you said "that finds the appropriate build of D via PARENT_ID". I don't know what this mean exactly. What has D done with Parent_Id that now one can search for it's contents? Did it archive the test results as a ZIP file and that zip file name is the parent_id?

Answer (score 3):

I came up with the following solution using declarative pipelines.

It requires installation of "copy artifact" plugin.

**In the downstream job**, set "env" variable with the path (or pattern path) to result file:

```
post {
  always {
    steps {
      script {
        // Rem: Must be BEFORE execution that may fail   
        env.RESULT_FILE='Devices\\resultsA.xml'
      }
      xunit([GoogleTest(
        pattern: env.RESULT_FILE,
      )])
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I use xunit but the same apply with junit

**In the parent job**, save build variables, then in post process I aggregate results with following code:

```
def runs=[]

pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Tests') {
      parallel {
        stage('test A') {
          steps {
            script {
              runs << build(job: "test A", propagate: false)
            }
          }
        }
        stage('test B') {
          steps {
            script {
              runs << build(job: "test B", propagate: false)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  post {
    always {
      script {
        currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
        def result_files = []
        runs.each {
          if (it.result != 'SUCCESS') {
            currentBuild.result = it.result
          }
          copyArtifacts(
            filter: it.buildVariables.RESULT_FILE,
            fingerprintArtifacts: true,
            projectName: it.getProjectName(),
            selector: specific(it.getNumber().toString())
          )
          result_files << it.buildVariables.RESULT_FILE
        }
        env.RESULT_FILE = result_files.join(',')
        println('Results aggregated from ' + env.RESULT_FILE)
      }
      archiveArtifacts env.RESULT_FILE
      xunit([GoogleTest(
        pattern: env.RESULT_FILE,
      )])
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the parent job also set the "env" variable so it can itself be aggregated by a parent job.

Comment: This is the most elegant and instructive solution to the general problem of aggregating downstream Jenkins test results that I found on the internet. Kudos. Is artifact fingerprinting strictly necessary for this to work?

Comment: @timblaku Aggregation is not strictly necessary. It is just a convenience to identify files since they are copied in several jobs.