# Aggregating test results in Jenkins with Parametrized Jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I understand this post is similar to:
[Aggregating results of downstream is no test in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808181/aggregating-results-of-downstream-is-no-test-in-jenkins)

and also to:
[Aggregating results of downstream parameterised jobs in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534480/aggregating-results-of-downstream-parameterised-jobs-in-jenkins?rq=1)

Nonetheless, I am not able to figure out for my case, how to make this working. I am currently using Jenkins 1.655.

I have jobs A, B, C - A being the upstream job. What I want to do is to have A call B and B call C. All needs to **block** and wait for completion of the next. If one fails, all fails. B and C generate unit test reports. So I want to aggregate these reports in A and then Publish that result in A. So, here's the current setup of the jobs:

**Job A:**

Build Steps

1. Execute shell: `echo $(date) > aggregate`
2. Trigger Parametrized Buid Job: **Job B**

Post Build Steps

1. Aggregate downstream test results
2. **Record fingerprints** of files to track usage: set Files to fingerprint to `aggregate`
3. Publish JUnit test result report (report files from B and C)

**Job B:**

Build Steps

1. Copy artifacts from another project: copy from upstream job `aggregate` file
2. Run tests to generate unit test reports
3. Trigger Parametrized Build Job: **Job C**

> It ultimately fails here because `aggregate` is only archived in the
>   Post Build Steps of Job A. **How can I archive an artifact in the Build Step?**

Post Build Steps

1. Aggregate downstream test results (unit test.xml generated)
2. **Record fingerprints** of files to track usage: set Files to fingerprint to `aggregate`

I won't post Job C here for simplicity but it follows pretty much what B does.

So, summing it up, I want to have interlinked jobs that depend on each other and uses the parametrized plugin and the upstream job must aggregate the test results of all downstream.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. If you have no limitation on where to run your jobs you can always specify it to run on the same workspace\machine - this will solve all your issues.
2. If for some reason you can't run it on the same workspace, instead of using the copy artifact plugin you can use the link in Jenkins to the WS (guessing you're using [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)) so it'll be easy to wget the "aggregate" file from A job from the triggered job using the defined:  TRIGGERED_BUILD_NUMBER_="Last build number triggered" from A. This will also help you to keep track of the jobs B and C you triggered to get the artifacts from there.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help. So if I understand correctly, you're saying to archive the results in B and C. Then in the Post Build Steps of A, I must do a wget to the URL and retrieve it. Is this right? Thank you and will try this @Dvir669

Comment: What I am doing right now is copying the results from B and C straight into  A's workspace as post build steps for B and C.  Then I publish the results in A. That approach works, but prevents me from aggregating the results - which is something I would like to have.

Comment: Sorry about the late response - I was abroad :) 
I meant that you can take the actual file from the WORKSPACE of the job (for example - https://J_MASTER:PORT/job/Job_Name/ws/report.cvs) and download it directly to A without the need to move it to the master by archiving it.

When you have all the reports in the build part (and not the post build) you can load the test reports altogether in A - Archive everything and publish

Comment: Hey @Dvir669 Thanks for getting back to me. The problem with that approach is that I will not be able to aggregate the result of downstream reports, right? That's exactly what I am doing now, I followed your suggestion. But unfortunately aggregating does not work.

Comment: Ok, so there might be some miscommunication here (English is not my first language). I understood you want to publish all test results from A, B & C -> aggregate reports is to  collectively centralize the test reports from all jobs and to publish all in A. if that is exactly what you're doing now, publish all test reports from all jobs in A then what am I missing? Sorry for not understanding, but it seems you already do what you need :) When you say aggregating doesn't work - is there a plugin you're using? can you elaborate what doesn't work?

Comment: Hi again! In order to aggregate the results, as far as I know, you first need to create a fingerprinted file in A (that is my file aggregate in job A) and job B and C must copy this artifact so that the chain of jobs (in terms of aggregation) works.
Isn't it like that how the process works? I took this step sequence from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808181/aggregating-results-of-downstream-is-no-test-in-jenkins